# How to place on-load event handler with React Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I need help on react-leaflet for my map-based app. I am trying to add an on-load function where a function would execute on load once the client logged onto the map. But on react-leaflet, there is no `onLoad`.

Right now I simply have this:

```
function CenterCoords() {
    const map = useMapEvents({
        // TODO resolve onload
        layeradd() {
            map.locate()
            console.log('loading')
        },
        locationfound(e: any) {
            map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom())
        },
    })
    return null
}
```

I only used layeradd but I have no idea what that means and react-leaflet documentation offers no hint on its leaflet handler function. And if I rely on leaflet documentation, `load` and `loading` do not seem to work.

Answer (score 6):

The `MapContainer` component takes a `whenReady` prop, which is a function that fires when the map is ready.  It also takes a `whenCreated` prop, which is a function of the underlying leaflet `L.map` instance.  But you can do whatever you want with it:

```js
<MapContainer
  center={center}
  zoom={zoom}
  scrollWheelZoom={false}
  whenReady={() => {
    console.log("This function will fire once the map is created")
  }}
  whenCreated={(map) => {
    console.log("The underlying leaflet map instance:", map)
  }}>
    ...
</MapContainer>
```

`load` and `loading` events are more specific to layers, like tileLayers or imageLayers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use useEffect to run something after first render. With an empty array as second param in useEffect run only once.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  myFunction();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use change layeradd with mouseover

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).